# Excel-VBA: Insert Row below and get new row as Range

Tags: excel, insert, vba

How can I insert a new row below a range and then get a reference to that new row so I can populate it?

```
Dim newRow As Range
newRow = row.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

results in an object variable or width block variable not set error but the new row is inserted. I can't however seem to get a reference to it.

A second question is that in above could I'm iterating over range and inserting rows into that range. Will the insert affect the iteration?

Comment: How are you iterating over the range?

Comment: `For Each row In rng.Rows...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. Stupid VBA syntax. ;)

```
Set newRow = Rows(rowNumber + 1 & ":" & rowNumber + 1)
```

works. the important part beign the Set keyword.

Answer (score 1):

My prior statement was incorrect because I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  Below is an example of looping through a range and upon satisfying a condition, a row will be inserted below the current row in the loop.  A boolean is needed to then skip over the inserted row.

```
Sub InsertAfterLastRow()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1:B5") 'Arbritrary
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim InsertRow As Long
    Dim Inserted As Boolean
    Dim NewRow As Range

    Inserted = False

    For Each Row In Rng.Rows
        If Inserted = False Then
            If Row.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
                    Rows(Row.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Set NewRow = Range(Row.Row + 1 & ":" & Row.Row + 1)
                    NewRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Inserted"
                    Inserted = True
            Else
                Row.Cells(1, 1).Value = "No"
            End If
        Else
            'Avoid a double insert, skipping a row
            Inserted = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to select it, I want to get the now row a range object and thats what always fails.

Comment: I included the select to visibly show which row was inserted.  How do you want to populate the row?

Comment: Programmatically, thats why I need a reference to it. `Dim newRow As Range` and then `newRow = Rows(row.row + 1 & ":" & row.row + 1)` leads to the variable not set error.

Comment: As you had posted, the Set keyword is needed.  I updated the solution satisfy your last comment using newRow.

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling with a similar issue wanting to add or delete a variable number of rows at a point below a reference range (named range) without affecting the named range. First I determine how many rows to add (or remove) variable holding the number of rows = addR

`addR = 2 ' you'd use some logic to derive the value of addR
Rows(Range("OutputBlock").Row + 1).EntireRow.Resize(addR).insert`

Output block being my named range where I want to add the rows.